# $.when() not working in Mac OSX 10.6.8 Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, youtube-api

For Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 in Mac OSX 10.6.8, the following JSFiddle isn't working for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/NSTq3/

```
$.when(queryYoutube('bob+dylan')).done(function(youtube_response){
  console.log('done');
  console.log(youtube_response);
});

function queryYoutube(search_string){
    var src = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?" +
        "&v=2" +
        "&alt=json" +
        "&format=5" +
        "&orderby=relevance" +
        "&safeSearch=none" +
        "&q=" + search_string;

    console.log(src);

    var getJSON = $.getJSON(src);
    return getJSON;
}
```

I'm using $.when().done() to query Youtube Data API v2. The JSFiddle though works for me in Chrome of Mountain Lion as well as Firefox and Safari on Mac Snow Leopard.

In the other browsers it is printing "done" in the console. For the version of Chrome from Snow Leopard though I listed at the top, "done" is never printed and it seems like the .done() statement is never entered.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 29.0.1547.22 beta in 10.6.8.

Comment: Just tried it in Chrome 28 at BrowserStack, it works there, too.